# use of (+) sign in JSP for addition

Tags: jsp

i am trying to get the value of multiplication and addition of numbers but in jsp it is taking the (+) as concatenation and not as addition symbol

Here is my code

```
<html>
</head>
<body>
 <%= "Sum = " + 2*4*5*1+359 %>
</body>
</html>
```

The output i am getting is 40359 but it should be 399

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of  `<%= "Sum = " + 2*4*5*1+359 %>` use this `sum = <%= 2*4*5*1+359 %>`

Answer (score 2):

You will get expression clause details [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaov.html)

Try below:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

 sum = <%= 2*4*5*1+359 %>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Since the first argument is a String, then all the other arguments would be concatenated as  strings. I would recommend reading some Java book (like Bruce Eckel's Thinking in Java) or (even better) go directly to JLS.

Your problem could be solved by adding parentheses around the math expression:

```
<%= "Sum = " + (2*4*5*1+359) %>
```